# Combine 2 Arrays with a single Dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, dictionary

I currently fetching two JSON arrays and I am storing them in variables called json_one and json_two. Everything works fine, but now I would like to somehow combine them into one single array.

**How can I combine 2 Arrays with a single dictionary?**

json_one

```
[
  {
    "address": "1031 25th Street San Diego, CA 92102",
    "id": 1,
    "resource_type_id": 3,
  }
]
```

json_two

```
 [
   {
     "resource_id": 4,
   }
 [
```

I've Tried this....

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @favorite = @user.favorites.find(params[:id])
      @resource_data = []
      (@resource_data << @favorite.resource_type.community_resources.where(:id => @favorite.resource_id)).flatten!
      (@resource_data << @favorite.resource_type.district_resources.where(:id => @favorite.resource_id)).flatten!
      (@resource_data << @favorite.resource_type.military_resources.where(:id => @favorite.resource_id)).flatten!
      (@resource_data << @favorite.resource_type.school_resources.where(:id => @favorite.resource_id)).flatten!

      @favorite_data = []
      (@favorite_data << @favorite)

      json_one = @resource_data.to_json(:only => [:id, :resource_type_id,:district_id,
        :school_id, :name, :description, :website, :phone, :email, :address, :latitude, :longtude]) 

      json_two = @favorite_data.to_json(:only => [:resource_id])

      array1 = JSON.parse(json_one)
      array2 = JSON.parse(json_two)

      #array1 << array2
      #firsts = array2.map {|array2| array2.first}

      combined = [ array1.first.merge(array2.first) ]

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: data }
      end
  end

###but this is my result. 
###I would like both dictionaries to be combined into one.

[
  {
    "address": "1031 25th Street San Diego, CA 92102",
    "id": 1,
    "resource_type_id": 3,
  }
  {
    "resource_id": 4,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_one = "[{\"address\":\"1031 25th Street San Diego, CA 92102\",\"id\":1,\"resource_type_id\":3}]"
json_two = "[{\"resource_id\":4}]"

array1 = JSON.parse(json_one)
array2 = JSON.parse(json_two)

combined = [ array1.first.merge(array2.first) ]

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json:combined }
end
```

FWIW, I would do this without JSON:

```
combined = @resource_data.slice( :id, :resource_type_id,:district_id,
                                 :school_id, :name, :description, :website, 
                                 :phone, :email, :address, :latitude, :longtude ) 
                         .merge( @favorite_data.slice( :resource_id ))
```

This pulls out the desired attributes from `@resource_data`, and merges it with `@favorite_data resource_id` attribute.

See [Rails slice docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

Comment: You need to parse the JSON. array_1 and array_2 are parsed from the JSON: `array1 = JSON.parse(json_one)`

Comment: Not sure where that error is coming from. Can you puts `json_one` and `json_two`?

Comment: I don't think you need JSON. What are `@resource_data` and `@favorite`?

Comment: I've updated the code above, the favorite is a favorite ID, and resource_data depends on where it finds the data I need. but its always one dictionary of that resource.

Comment: I think the error comes from the fact that favorite is not a dictionary to start, just an ID

Comment: I solved it, thanks. your answer was helpful. i saw what i did wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with a better way of doing it.